# jQuery live color switcher

Tags: jquery, html, color-picker

> *I try to make jquery live color switcher but i need to know is it possible add some plugin who change a background color like* **header** *or* **body**

Now I use jQuery MiniColors 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple javascript to get the element and change the background color using

```
document.getElementById('Id name here').style.background = color;
```

or you can use jQuery and use:

```
$('bodyIdOrClassName').css('backgroundColor', '#FF0000');
```

but with your color of course.

EDIT: using style.background is better than using .bgColor.

Using your JsFiddle: add this to the change function:

```
                change: function(hex, opacity) {

                    // ADD THIS LINE
                    $('body').css('backgroundColor', hex);
                }
```

Here's a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/KNWVv/

Comment: @KarolHotár: You need to be more specific, this is the solution to your question, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to achieve that ...when i choose color on colorPicker a header or body change the background color automatically